# Using localhost as WMS Server

Tags: qgis, wms, server

I installed OSGEO4w (selecting Qgis Desktop 2.12, Qgis Server and Apache Web Server) on Windows 7 because I must publish some Qgis project on my pc as server. 
I have a problem to set my pc as Server WMS. 
When I try to execute "Add layer from WMS Server" and click on `Search Server` I do not find my localhost, if I try to create "new server" setting URL as `http://localhost`  and click on Connect button I receive following message:

> "The server you are trying to connect does not appear to be a WMS
>   server . Check the URL address ."

and in "show detail" for error I obtain:

Instead of the string of capabilities, it received the following response :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>OSGeo4W - OSGeo for Windows</title>
<style type="text/css"> <!-- body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px} --> </style></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="#0000FF">

OSGeo4W - OSGeo for Windows 

 Installed Web Applications and Features 
<p>There are currently 
   2 osgeo4w applications   installed. 
</p>
Apache 2.2.8: 
<blockquote>
  <p>Manual</p>
</blockquote>
PHP 5.2.5: 
<blockquote>
  <p>phpinfo</p>
</blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The Mapserver documentation indicates that the server URLs should look more like this: `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=mywms.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities`, see [here](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html).

Comment: As well as incorrect URL given, another  problem may be that you haven't installed a WMS, for example the home page you reference, only suggests `Apache 2.2.8` and `PHP 5.2.5` are installed